# How to use lib-sodium in HTML page by using CDN

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, libsodium

Hi I am trying to use libsodium as CDN in my HTML page

code is

```
<script>
    window.sodium = {
        onload: function (sodium) {
            let h = sodium.crypto_generichash(64, sodium.from_string('test'));
            console.log(sodium.to_hex(h));
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="sodium.js" async></script>
```

it is same as show on
https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js

but I got error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ready')

how to use this  libsodium.js in html page ?

Comment: is this the only code in the page?

Comment: @Greedo its javascript code I have put in my html footer before body

Comment: Yes, I ask if this is the only code. Also, the sodium.js file is correctly stored locally ?

Comment: yes same folder I also check its downloaded in chrome network tab status code 200